# Calculating a time and comparing it with a mysql time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime, unix-timestamp

PHP:

```
$current = time();
$time_ago = $current - 45*60; // get the time 45 mts ago.
```

MySQL:

I have a table status which has a datetime column 'modified';

I am trying to query the table to get the rows that have a modified time lower than that of `$time_ago;`

My PHP Code:

```
$this->db->select("(SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(status.modified) FROM status WHERE status_id = 0) AS modified_timestamp" , FALSE);
        $this->db->from('status');
        $this->db->where('status_id', 0);
        $this->db->where('modified_timestamp <', $time_ago);
        $this->db->limit(25);
        $q = $this->db->get();
```

Getting a db error:

> Unknown column 'modified_timestamp' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(status.modified) FROM status WHERE status_id = 0) AS modified_timestamp 
    FROM (status) WHERE `status_id` = 0 AND `modified_timestamp` < 1343542758 LIMIT 25
```

Comment: modified_timestamp is a temp table not a column

Comment: the error is itself is pretty descriptive that modified_timesatamp column does not exists in table check your spelling

Comment: Brandon, thanks for pointing that out.. it is a temp table.  My sql is pretty rusty. How would I write this query?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You realize you can use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() in a where clause, right?

```
$this->db->select("UNIX_TIMESTAMP(modified)" , FALSE);
$this->db->from('status');
$this->db->where('status_id', 0);
$this->db->where('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(modified) <', $time_ago);
$this->db->limit(25);
$q = $this->db->get();
```

Note: May not work as-is, I haven't used this particular DB API, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea.  I shall try it out. I wasn't aware that I could use UNIX_TIMESTAMP in the where clause.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it! You can accept the answer if you approve.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->from('status');
$this->db->where('status_id', 0);
$this->db->where('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(modified) <', $time_ago);
$this->db->limit(25);
```

Comment: Thanks much..I shall try it out.. I wasn't aware that we could use unix_timestamp in the where clause

Comment: Just use the query by SilverbackNet and that should do it